# iOS 5 Reminders on weekdays only

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

Is it possible to create repeating reminders for weekdays only?  I don't see this option, but I can't believe something so basic would be left off.

Comment: If you need to be reminded of something every weekday, you may be better of with setting an alarm. Reminders are more like a task list kind of thing.

Comment: The thing is, the reminders already have a way to repeat everyday.  I just can't believe repeat "every weekday" isn't also an option.  That seems to me much more useful.

Comment: bugreport.apple.com is just a few mouse clicks away...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating a reminder on monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, and friday, with each one repeating weekly? You'll have to make five edits instead of just one whenever something changes, but maybe the event details won't change enough and this workaround will suffice.

Comment: Man, it sucks that this is the best solution. If you need 4 weekday alerts, you need to set 20 reminders. Apple, this does not `just work`

Comment: As Stephen Lafredo mentioned in his answer, you can create one with a custom weekly repeat time that happens every weekday, or whichever days of the week you want.

Answer (score 28):

In Reminders.

1. Select Repeat
2. Select Weekly
3. Select Custom
4. Select the days, e.g. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: They hid this feature _really_ well.

Answer (score 16):

If you have an iPhone 4S, or newer, ask Siri to create the reminder for weekdays.  She can do it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Really? Reminders app has no setting for this.

Comment: @MildFuzz Yeap, surprisingly some things can only be done through Siri.

Comment: Except that it does, I've used this feature since the early days

Answer (score 8):

Add Calendar event for weekdays only by selecting Every Week, then Custom, which will then allow you to click which days of the week you want.  Once select, M-F, it will confirm you selected every weekday.  It will then show up as Custom on your Calendar event.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to create custom reminder time is by Siri.  I managed to created an event to remind me every 3 days.  I haven't figure out how to create one on weekdays only.  In the mean time, I just create an alarm as above post suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I already saw this answer, but this may help find that custom option it's not immediately obvious: On calendar, choose repeat.  In repeat chose custom, then choose weekly, then select Monday-Friday.   You'll see 5 check marks

Another example of custom use is to get a meeting for every selected day of the week and week of the month, say every 3rd Thursday.  Select custom repeat, choose monthly, then "on the" gives the default choice of a date, but click the arrow and you get the choice on the 1st, 2nd, etc Mon Tues etc

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to setup a weekday (Monday-Friday) reminder using the Reminders app for iOS is to open Siri as others have mentioned and say **"REMIND ME WEEKDAYS AT 2PM (whatever time you want obviously)."**

Siri when then ask you what you want to be reminded about which is when you provide the title of your reminder.

After you confirm the reminder it will save and if done correctly you'll notice the reminder will say "custom repeat".

If you edit the reminder you will lose your custom repeat so do not make changes after creating the reminder with Siri.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to do it. Provided you have Siri of course. Also, you can add the subject you want to be reminded about. I just created a reminder with "Remind me to listen to Zane Lowe every weekday at 6 pm". Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am an app developer working with Reminders, and this kind of this is possible on the underlying APIs. The Reminder app is quite bare bones in its functionality.  I think this is intentional.

I realize this may not help your immediate situation, but the more I work with Reminders, the more I think that apple has intentionally made Reminders pretty basic, because they are hoping app developers will create the kind of functionality you are looking for, in custom apps.

Unfortunately, at this stage not many developers seem to be taking up that challenge, each preferring do do reminders/timers/todo list in their own separate universes.

What you want could be done, but someone would need to make an app to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Mavericks, I found that there is an easy way to do this in iCal, but it's not obvious. Instead of selecting "Every Day" go to Custom, then select Weekly, and you'll see a list of the 7 weekdays. Choose "Every 1 week(s) on:" then click on MTWTF or any combination of days, and you're all set.

In fact, after you do this, it will say Custom...Every Weekday.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP wants to know how to do this in Calendar on iOS. They may not have a Mac and therefore would not have access to the OS X Calendar app.

Answer (score 0):

Choose "Custom" in repeat section and choose the days of the week for your calendar.